# Numpy: outer product of n vectors

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to do something simple in numpy, and I'm sure there should be an easy way of doing it.

Basically, I have a list of `n` vectors with various lengths. If `v1[i]` is the `i`'th entry of the first vector then I want to find a `n`-dimensional array, A, such that

```
A[i,j,k...] = v1[i] v2[j] v3[k] ...
```

My problem is that:

1. `outer` only takes two *vector* arguments.
2. `einsum` requires a parameter like "abcd..." which seems unnecessary.
3. `kron` requires what seems like rather complex reshaping, and takes only two arguments.

I'd like to avoid as much complexity as possible, so as to avoid introducing bugs. So preferably I would like a single command.

So far, the best I have some up with is:

```
 vs = [v1, v2, v3 ...]
 shape = map(len, vs)

 # specify the orientation of each vector
 newshapes = diag(array(shape)-1)+1
 reshaped = [x.reshape(y) for x,y in zip(vs, newshapes)]

 # direct product
 A = reduce(lambda a,b: a*b, reshaped, 1)
```

Comment: The number of vectors is unknown until runtime?

Comment: @DarenW yes, that is correct.

Comment: I like this `reduce(lambda a, b: a[..., np.newaxis] * b, vs)` but I'm not sure whether that can be considered "a single command". Or if there're faster ways.

Comment: @jorgeca nice. It definitely wont be slower than my method.

Comment: Have you looked at itertools.combinations?

Comment: @Nirk The closest `itertools` equivalent is the direct product as implemented by `itertools.product` but this iterates through the elements (or indexes) so the construct would be something like (will single line it...) `for index, value in zip(product(*map(lambda x: range(len(x)),vs)),product(*vs)): output[value] = prod(value)`, not sure I like it.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you don't know the number of vectors till runtime you could still use `np.einsum` like this:

`np.einsum(','.join([chr(i+97) for i in xrange(len(vs))]),*vs)`

...although you're right that it's ugly as hell!

Comment: @ali_m Yup, I considered that. I really don't like the way it is constrained by the number of letters you can use. Admittedly, this is pretty a pretty unlikely situation and memory constraints will be problem before I run out of letters, unless many of the vectors are length 1. But I don't think this is a good enough excuse when you can do it without such a constraint. As you said, ugly as hell!

Comment: `np.einsum('i,j,k', a, b, c)` is equivalent to `np.einsum(a, [0], b, [1], c, [2])`, which is an easier notation to build at runtime, see the docs. On the other hand, if your true objective is avoiding bugs, stay away from cryptic one-liners that take 10 minutes to figure out. WRT that I found this older essay by GvR enlightening: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

Comment: @Jaime Yeah, I tried cobbling something together using that syntax as well. It does avoid the number of letters constraint, but the one-liner is actually even more monstrous! It's not worth it, as you say - `np.einsum` is only quicker than these other methods for quite small arrays.

Comment: @Jamie Perhaps if GvR visualised `reduce`s as a little guy going along collecting up data and putting it in a sack he might have the same fondness of `reduce` that I do. Leave him alone Rossum!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use use following one line code:

```
reduce(np.multiply, np.ix_(*vs))
```

`np.ix_()` will do the outer broadcast, you need reduce, but you can pass the ufunc `np.multiply` without lambda function.

Here is the comparing:

```
import numpy as np
vs = [np.r_[1,2,3.0],np.r_[4,5.0],np.r_[6,7,8.0]]
shape = map(len, vs)

 # specify the orientation of each vector
newshapes = np.diag(np.array(shape)-1)+1
reshaped = [x.reshape(y) for x,y in zip(vs, newshapes)]

# direct product
A = reduce(lambda a,b: a*b, reshaped, 1)
B = reduce(np.multiply, np.ix_(*vs))

np.all(A==B)
```

The reuslt:

```
True
```

Comment: +1 It may be a negligible improvement, unless your vector lists are really long, but I would think that numpy's `np.multiply.reduce(np-ix_(vs))` would probably perform better than the Python construct.

Answer (score 4):

There is an alternative line of code:

```
reduce(np.multiply.outer, vs)
```

It is more transparent for me than `np.ix_(*vs)` construction and support multidimensional arrays like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24839481/2379045).

Timings are the same within a tolerance:

```
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

def outer1(*vs):
    return np.multiply.reduce(np.ix_(*vs))
def outer2(*vs):
    return reduce(np.multiply.outer, vs)

v1 = np.random.randn(100)
v2 = np.random.randn(200)
v3 = np.random.randn(300)
v4 = np.random.randn(50)

%timeit outer1(v1, v2, v3, v4)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 796 ms per loop

%timeit outer2(v1, v2, v3, v4)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 795 ms per loop

np.all(outer1(v1, v2, v3, v4) == outer2(v1, v2, v3, v4))
# True
```

Comment: Yeah, I'd prefer to use that.

Answer (score 0):

this is also a one line code that works well:

```
functools.reduce(lambda mt1, mt2: np.outer(m1,m2).reshape(m1.shape + m2.shape), vs)
```

takes same time as:

```
functools.reduce(np.multiply, np.ix_(*vs))
```

but I think it is more clear