# Numpy: Multiple Outer Products

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**General Problem**

Suppose that I have a `ndarray` `v` of shape `(nrow,ncols,3)`. I want to compute the ndarray `outer_array` of shape `(nrow,ncols,3,3)` containing all outer products of the vectors of shape `(3)` at each index `(nrow,ncol)`. Of course, this is the the kind of problem for which `numpy.einsum` exists.
Now, what I've tried is:

```
outer_array = numpy.einsum("xyi,xyj->xyij",v,v.conjugate())
```

Now, I'm not sure that this will work: despite the fact that `outer_array` has the expected shape, the elements of the matrices of outer products do not correspond to what I'm expecting.

I think this is due to the choice of labels in the `einsum` expression: the product is supposed to be summed over `x` and `y` because the indices are repeated, but since I'm reusing them in the output expression, the result of the sum is somehow broadcast.

On the other hand, if I write:

```
outer_array = numpy.einsum("xyi,uvj->...ij",v,v.conjugate())
```

numpy will compute all possible combinations of outer products for each pair `(x,y)` and `(u,v)`, resulting in an array of shape `(ncols,nrow,ncols,nrow,3,3)`, where the diagonals  `(u,v) = (x,y)` will contain the desired output.

**The Precise Question**

How do I choose the first two indices in the einsum notation in order to obtain an array where at each index `x,y` I get the outer product of vector `v` with itself without having to resort to the second expression?

**Edit**
apparently, this form seems to work too:

```
outer_array = numpy.einsum("...i,...j->...ij",v,v.conjugate())
```

I can only admire how useful numpy broadcasting is!

Comment: Can you post an example of output "not corresponding to what you are expecting"? Your first approach does seem like the right thing to do.

Comment: You are right indeed. The problem of the unexpected result was due to another issue. I still wonder how does my code manages to work, since the indices `x` and `y` are repeated in the terms to be summed over and appear in the output again. Can someone explain that?

Comment: this might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17138393/1461210

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to `'xyi,xyj->xyij'` working is that the `xy` is repeated in the output string.

Let's use a simpler array:

```
x = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)
np.einsum.einsum('ij->j',x)
# array([6, 9])  # sums on the 1st dimension of `x`
```

Now for an outer product on this `x`:

```
In [20]: x[:,:,None]*x[:,None,:]  # shape (3,2,2)
Out[20]: 
array([[[ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  1]],

       [[ 4,  6],
        [ 6,  9]],

       [[16, 20],
        [20, 25]]])
```

This is an example of numpy broadcasting (i.e. adding dimensions and expanding them)

In `"...i,...j->...ij"`, `...` is functioning more as a place holder for existing, but anonymous dimensions.

The equivalent with `einsum` is:

```
np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk',x,x)
```

(I should really do a calculation that isn't symmetric in the last 2 dimensions).

I've worked out a pure Python work-alike of `einsum`.  The focus is on parsing the argument string, and how it creates the inputs for an `iter` object.  It's available on github: https://github.com/hpaulj/numpy-einsum/blob/master/einsum_py.py   You are welcome to play around with it. It has a `debug` flag to show intermediate steps.

With my einsum with debugging output:

```
In [23]: einsum_py.myeinsum('ij,ik->ijk',x,x,debug=True)
# ... some parsing information
[('ij', [105, 106], 'NONE'), ('ik', [105, 107], 'NONE')]
('ijk', [105, 106, 107], 'NONE')
iter labels: [105, 106, 107],'ijk'

op_axes [[0, 1, -1], [0, -1, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
```

`op_axes` is the key argument that is used in creating a `iter`, the object that iterates over the axes of the input and output arrays.  It iterates over the 1st axis of all arrays.  The 2nd axis is 1 for 1st op and output, and a `newaxis` (-1) for the 2nd op.

With the `ellipsis`:

```
In [24]: einsum_py.myeinsum('...j,...k->...jk',x,x,debug=True)
...
iter labels: [0, 106, 107],'0jk'
op_axes [[0, 1, -1], [0, -1, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
```

This generates the same `op_axes`, and hence the same calculation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Another very simple question: what is the  exact effect of repeating `XY` in the output string? Does is suppress the summation over those indices?

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#reduction-iteration - `Whenever a writeable operand has fewer elements than the full iteration space, that operand is undergoing a reduction.`  In other words, it's the missing `xy` that triggers summation.