# Python - Matrix outer product

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Given two matrices

```
A: m * r
B: n * r
```

I want to generate another matrix `C: m * n`, with each entry `C_ij` being a matrix calculated by the outer product of `A_i` and `B_j`.

For example,

```
A: [[1, 2],
    [3, 4]]

B: [[3, 1],
    [1, 2]]
```

gives

```
C: [[[3, 1],  [[1 ,2],
     [6, 2]],  [2 ,4]],
     [9, 3],  [[3, 6],
     [12,4]],  [4, 8]]]
```

I can do it using for loops, like

```
    for i in range (A.shape(0)):
      for j in range (B.shape(0)):
         C_ij = np.outer(A_i, B_j)
```

I wonder If there is a vectorised way of doing this calculation to speed it up?

Comment: Do you want a 4D, `(m, n, r, r)`-shape array, or do you want a 2D, `(m, n)`-shape array of `object` dtype where each element is another array? I would strongly recommend the first option, but your description sounds closer to the second.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I prefer the first one, a 4D `(m, n, r, r)`-shape array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
temp = numpy.multiply.outer(A, B)
C = numpy.swapaxes(temp, 1, 2)
```

NumPy ufuncs, such as `multiply`, have an [`outer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html#numpy.ufunc.outer) method that almost does what you want. The following:

```
temp = numpy.multiply.outer(A, B)
```

produces a result such that `temp[a, b, c, d] == A[a, b] * B[c, d]`. You want `C[a, b, c, d] == A[a, c] * B[b, d]`. The `swapaxes` call rearranges [`temp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html#numpy.swapaxes) to put it in the order you want.

Answer (score 18):

The Einstein notation expresses this problem nicely

```
In [85]: np.einsum('ac,bd->abcd',A,B)
Out[85]: 
array([[[[ 3,  1],
         [ 6,  2]],

        [[ 1,  2],
         [ 2,  4]]],


       [[[ 9,  3],
         [12,  4]],

        [[ 3,  6],
         [ 4,  8]]]])
```

Comment: Man, I ought to learn that notation. Every time someone posts an answer using it, it's always way shorter than what I come up with. Probably more understandable too, if you know the Einstein summation convention.

Answer (score 1):

## Simple Solution with Numpy Array Broadcasting

Since, you want `C_ij = A_i * B_j`, this can be achieved simply by numpy broadcasting on element-wise-product of column-vector-A and row-vector-B, as shown below:

```py
# import numpy as np
# A = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
# B = [[3, 1], [1, 2]]
A, B = np.array(A), np.array(B)
C = A.reshape(-1,1) * B.reshape(1,-1)
# same as: 
# C = np.einsum('i,j->ij', A.flatten(), B.flatten())
print(C)
```

**Output**:

```
array([[ 3,  1,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  2,  2,  4],
       [ 9,  3,  3,  6],
       [12,  4,  4,  8]])
```

You could then get your desired four sub-matrices by using [`numpy.dsplit()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dsplit.html#numpy.dsplit) or [`numpy.array_split()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy.array_split) as follows:

```py
np.dsplit(C.reshape(2, 2, 4), 2)
# same as:
# np.array_split(C.reshape(2,2,4), 2, axis=2)
```

**Output**:

```
[array([[[ 3,  1],
         [ 6,  2]],

        [[ 9,  3],
         [12,  4]]]), 
array([[[1, 2],
         [2, 4]],

        [[3, 6],
         [4, 8]]])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
C = numpy.tensordot(A, B, axes=0)
```

`tensordot` does exactly what you want. The `axes` parameter is used to in addition perform sums over certain axes (for >2d tensors, the default value is `2` and it will sum away 2 axes of each of the arrays), but by setting it to `0` it simply doesn't reduce the dimensions and keeps the whole outer product.

Answer (score 0):

Use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/);

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [3]: B = np.array([[3, 1], [1, 2]])

In [4]: C = np.outer(A, B)

In [5]: C
Out[5]: 
array([[ 3,  1,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  2,  2,  4],
       [ 9,  3,  3,  6],
       [12,  4,  4,  8]])
```

Once you have the desired result, you can use `numpy.reshape()` to mold it in almost any shape you want;

```
In [6]: C.reshape([4,2,2])
Out[6]: 
array([[[ 3,  1],
        [ 1,  2]],

       [[ 6,  2],
        [ 2,  4]],

       [[ 9,  3],
        [ 3,  6]],

       [[12,  4],
        [ 4,  8]]])
```

Comment: I'm kind of surprised this is so visually close to what the OP wants, but despite the resemblance, it's still not quite right. If you visualize the desired result as a big 2D grid with little 2D grids in the the cells, this is what you'd get by gluing all the little grids together at the edges to make one grid.

Comment: Yes, agree with you. Perhaps first do `np.outer(A, B)` and then divide it into smaller grids?

Comment: But this will give a different result. I wanted the inner matrices to be `[[3, 1], [6, 2]]`, `[[1, 2], [2, 4]]`, `[[9, 3], [12, 4]]` and `[[3, 6], [4, 8]]`.