# Efficient generation of high-dimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have `n` dimensions, each equipped with an array of values, and in addition I have an operator (such as `np.prod`, or any other operator which acts on a numpy array).

I wish to generate an `n`-dimensional array `arr`, such that `arr[a1,a2,...,an]` will return the result of my operator on the `a1`'s value of the first array, the `a2`'s value of the second array, etc.

A low-dimensional example may make it clearer:

```
import numpy as np

def generate(operator, *arrays):
    ...

arr_1 = np.array([0.5, 0.3, 0.2])
arr_2 = np.array([0.2, 0.3, 0.5])
arr_3 = np.array([0.4, 0.7])

arr = generate(np.prod, arr1, arr2, arr3)
print arr[0, 1, 1] == 0.5 * 0.3 * 0.7
## Prints True

arr_max = generate(np.max, arr1, arr2, arr3)
print arr[2, 1, 0]
## Prints 0.4
```

A loop seems rather slow, and since I am not used to vector-thinking, I post this question.

Another related question: how large can I hope this array to be?

## Edit

As requested, here's a possible output of `generate(np.prod, arr1, arr2, arr3)`:

```
array([[[ 0.04 ,  0.07 ],
        [ 0.06 ,  0.105],
        [ 0.1  ,  0.175]],

       [[ 0.024,  0.042],
        [ 0.036,  0.063],
        [ 0.06 ,  0.105]],

       [[ 0.016,  0.028],
        [ 0.024,  0.042],
        [ 0.04 ,  0.07 ]]])
```

I also wish to add that the signature of `generate` is not important to me; any other way of plugging the input would be ok as well.

Comment: I'm not really seeing how this can be a 3 dimensional matrix as `arr[2,1,0]` implies.  Could you post an example output of what you want to see?

Comment: I've added the example you've asked for; to generate it, I've used the following code: `arr_1[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis] * arr_2[np.newaxis,:,np.newaxis] * arr_3[np.newaxis,np.newaxis,:]`. Quite clumsy, but I am not sure how to do it better.

Comment: I think using newaxis (or None does the same thing in slice notation) is fine, but you can look up "outer", e.g., `numpy.multiply.outer()`.

Comment: `numpy.multiply.outer` seems to work on 2 arrays only, and it is not sure how to apply that `.outer` to a function which is not already a numpy `ufunc`, such as a custom function I write.

Comment: This can either be easy or difficult. What operations do you really need? What do you need to apply them to? Are you sure you need to take into account the combination of differently shaped arrays? If you can be more specific, a simple solution is probably at hand. From the other comments, it looks like this may be solvable with some broadcasting. How generic do you want to be in dimension?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Numpy: outer product of n vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138393/numpy-outer-product-of-n-vectors)