# NumPy: Sparse outer product of n vectors (hyperbolic cross)

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, numpy

I'm trying to compute a certain subset of the full outer product of `n` vectors. The computation of the full outer product is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138393/numpy-outer-product-of-n-vectors).

Formally: Let `v1`,`v2`,...,`vk` be vectors of some length `n`, and `K` be a positive constant. I want a list containing all the products `v1[i1]v2[i2]...vk[ik]` for which `i1*i2*...*ik <= K` (indices start at one). Note: For example, if `K = n ** k`, the list would contain every combination.

My current approach is to create a hierarchical list of the indices fulfilling the condition above and then calculating the products recursively, which has the advantage of reusing some factors.

This implementation is a lot slower than the computation of the full outer product using NumPy (for same `n` and `k`). I want to achieve a better performance than the computation of the full product. I'm interested in *larger* values for `k`, and *small* `K` (this problem comes from function approximation with sparse bases, i.e. hyperbolic cross).

Does anyone know a more performant way to get this list? Maybe by using more NumPy or another algorithm? I will try a C implementation next.

Here is my current implementation:

```
import numpy as np

def get_cross_indices(n, k, K):
    """
    Assume k > 0.
    Returns a hierarchical list containg elements of type
      (i1, list) with
        - i1 being a index (zero based!)
        - list being again a list (possibly empty) with all indices i2, such
          that (i1+1) * (i2+1) * ... * (ik+1) <= K  (going down the hierarchy)
    """
    if k == 1:
        num = min(n, K)
        return (num, [(x, []) for x in range(num)])
    else:
        indices = []
        nums = 0
        for i in xrange(min(n, K)):
            (num, tail) = get_cross_indices(n,
                k - 1, K // (i + 1))
            indices.append((i,  tail))
            nums += num
        return (nums, indices)

def calc_cross_outer_product(vectors, result, factor, indices, pos):
    """
    Fills the result list recursively with all products
        vectors[0][i1] * ... * vectors[k-1][ik]

    such that i1,...,ik is a feasible index sequence
    from `indices` (they are in there hierarchically,
    also see `get_cross_indices`).
    """
    for (x, list) in indices:
        if not list:
            result[pos] = factor * vectors[0][x]
            pos += 1
        else:
            pos = calc_cross_outer_product(vectors[1:], result,
                factor * vectors[0][x], list, pos)
    return pos

k = 3 # number of vectors
n = 4 # vector length
K = 3
# using random values here just for demonstration purposes
vectors = np.random.rand(k, n)

# get all indices which meet the condition
(count, indices) = get_cross_indices(n, k, K)

result = np.ones(count)
calc_cross_outer_product(vectors, result, 1, indices, 0)


## Equivalent version ##
alt_result = np.ones(count)
# create full outer products
outer_product = reduce(np.multiply, np.ix_(*vectors))
pos = 0
for inds in np.ndindex((n,)*k):
    # current index set is feasible?
    if np.product(np.array(inds) + 1) <= K:
        # compute [ vectors[0][inds[0]],...,vectors[k-1][inds[k-1]] ]
        values = map(lambda x: vectors[x[0]][x[1]],
            np.dstack((np.arange(k), inds))[0])
        alt_result[pos] = np.product(values)
        pos += 1
```

To get a visual idea of the *indices* I'm interested in, here is a picture for `k=3`, `K=n`:

[image: Hyperbolic Cross]

(taken from [this website](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~potts/nfft/nsfft.php?druck))

Comment: If indexing gets too confusing compared to simple loops, I usually write a swig wrapper and the generating function in C. This achievs good performance (parellel execution with openmp easily possible), maintains logic and readibility and fits nicely as function in between my numpy calls. Since this is no "pure" numpy solution I leave it here as a comment.

Comment: Could you show the code of your current solution, and a minumal working example with expected input and output ? As it is not easy to follow how the this is supposed to work exactly. In particular there could be multiple sets of indices that verify `i1*i2*...*ik < K`, so how do you know which ones to take? or am I missing something? (this condition is not mentioned in the other post about the outer product you link to).

Comment: So is a regular cross product just this with `k` and `K` both equal to 2 or 3?  Are you summing any of the products?